# ajax sending data to the code behind not working

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.aspx/check_phone_no_server",
    data: "{'Email':'" + $('#phoneno').val() + "'}",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
        if (response.d != "0")
            alert("1 is heere");
        else {
            alert("0 is heere");
        }
    }
});




[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string check_phone_no_server(string Email)
    {
        //index a = new index();
        //return a.check_phone_no();
        return Email.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What's your exact question?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply pass the data as an `Object`, not as a `String`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.aspx/check_phone_no_server",
    data: {
        Email: $('#phoneno').val() //will probably not be phoneno
    },
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
        if (response.d != "0")
            alert("1 is heere");
        else {
            alert("0 is heere");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well now your data is in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format but your content type says `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: My bad. I usually don't even put `contentType` when using ajax XD